# problems with Bibtex/Texify after updates

Tags: bibtex

After my last update, I cannot compile my PhD Thesis any longer (that has worked for years w/o problems. This is the message that I get at texify.log

```
2016-01-16 22:38:06,452+0100 FATAL texify - BibTeX failed for some reason.
2016-01-16 22:38:06,453+0100 FATAL texify - Info: 
2016-01-16 22:38:06,453+0100 FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
2016-01-16 22:38:06,453+0100 FATAL texify - Line: 1267
```

Comment: This will be very hard to solve unless you provide some more information (e.g. what OS are you using, what TeX distribution you're using, and especially what version of TeXify is giving you this problem).

Comment: I had same problem today ...download miktex distro..run iti...after run update wizard it will update 1 miktex package..updater as i remember..after this run update wizard again and select and update packages

Comment: Win 10 64bit, Miktex 2.9.5823-x64

Comment: I have reinstalled Miktex several times already and I tried it with the latest updates and w/o the updates - both don't work

Comment: try miktex 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

You can't separate authors by comma if you have multiple authors. You have to use [and] instead of comma [,].

This is bad:

```
@Book{williamson,
author={Williamson, David P, Shmoys, David B},
year = {2010},
title = {The Design of Approximation Algorithms},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
}
```

This is good:

```
@Book{williamson,
author={Williamson, David P and Shmoys, David B},
year = {2010},
title = {The Design of Approximation Algorithms},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
}
```